# How to animate font size of text node in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to know if there's a way to animate the text size of a node (e.g `Label`), like change the text size via transition? I tried to set a `Timeline` for the `fontProperty()` of the node, but nothing really happened:

```
Label label = new Label(); // The text node
Font font = Font.font(100); // Change the text size to 100
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
  new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(label.fontProperty(), label.getFont())),
  new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), new KeyValue(label.fontProperty(), font))
);
```

The only way I can think of is, scale the **ACTUAL** size of the node. But the downside is, it changes the layout of the node as well (the position varies with its size). Additionally, it is not accurate if you really want the text size to be as big/small as a specific `font-size` value.

```
Label label = new Label(); // The text node
double size = 2; // Scale the size by 2
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
  new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
    new KeyValue(label.scaleXProperty(), label.getScaleX()),
    new KeyValue(label.scaleYProperty(), label.getScaleY())),
  new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),
    new KeyValue(label.scaleXProperty(), size),
    new KeyValue(label.scaleYProperty(), size))
);
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

---

## UPDATE

The formula I'm using with this transition (this is just in case I forgot or lost my source code so I could go back here, as well as to share it here).

```
@Override
protected void interpolate(double frac) {

    // Determine which is less/greater value between the initial and
    // ending value, then get their difference. This is to resolve the
    // end value when we either increase or decrease the initial value.
    double min = Math.min(start, end); // returns the smaller value
    double max = Math.max(start, end); // returns the higher value
    double diff = max - min; // the positive difference between the two value.

    // Since our start will always be the initial value regardless if
    // it is greater or less than the end, we will simply increase or
    // decrease its value until it reaches the desired end value.
    // Also, computing the difference between their value was to determine
    // if they both have equal values, it means (max - min) is always 0
    // as well as multiplying it to frac, therefore, there will be a
    // 0 value to increase or decrease.
    double size = (start == min) ?
                   start + (diff * frac) : // start is smaller so we'll just increase its value
                   start - (diff * frac); // decrease if it has the higher value than end

    UIcontrol.setFont(Font.font(size));
}
```

Comment: With a [`ScaleTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/ScaleTransition.html) you can animate the scale of the label, which, afaik, doesn't change the layout. Otherwise you have to set a new font with an interpolated size at each `KeyFrame`, which doesn't work out of the box. Maybe bind it to a `DoubleProperty` on which you listen to a change notification, which you use to create and set the font.

Comment: @M.leRutte I'll try it now with `ScaleTransition` instead of timeline.

Comment: @M.leRutte The interpolated size is useful btw. Thank you for pointing that out. I never thought about it. +1

Comment: Guess it's never too late to comment: You can get the positive difference between the two much easier: `double diff = Math.abs(start - end)`. Your way is very creative though, would not have thought of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example that implements a custom `Interpolator`.

You can explore the other methods in the `Transition` class from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html). Note there the properties inherited from class [javafx.animation.Animation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html) !

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.scene.control.Labeled;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TextSizeTransition extends Transition{

    private Labeled UIcontrol; // a little generic -> subclasses: ButtonBase, Cell, Label, TitledPane
    private int start, end; // initial and final size of the text

    public TextSizeTransition(Labeled UIcontrol, int start, int end, Duration duration) {
        this.UIcontrol = UIcontrol;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end - start; // minus start because of (end * frac) + start in interpolate() 
        setCycleDuration(duration);  
        setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR); 
        //setCycleCount(100);
        // and a lot of other methods 
    }

    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        // frac value goes from 0 to 1
        // when frac is zero -> size is start
        // when frac is 1 -> size is end + start 
        //(that's why we this.end = end - start; above to back to original end value)
        int size = (int) ((end * frac) + start);
        if(size<=end) {
            UIcontrol.setFont(Font.font(size));
        }else { // once the size reaches the destination (i.e. end value)
            // back to the start size if you want
            //UIcontrol.setFont(Font.font(start));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Example**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TextAnimation extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {

    Label label = new Label("Text Size Animation");
    Pane root = new Pane(label);
    root.setPrefSize(1100, 300);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    // transit text size from 10 to 100 during 5 seconds
    TextSizeTransition trans = new TextSizeTransition(label, 10, 100,Duration.millis(5000));

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    trans.play();
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: gif]